# Return an array value from included file in a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, if-statement, include

Ok, stupid question, I guess...

I'm trying to do this:

**File:** pt.php

```
<?php $langlist = array ( "Car" => "Carro", "Big Car" => "Carro grande") ?>
```

**File:** index.php

```
<?php
$lang = 'pt';
if ($lang != 'en') include('locale/' . $lang . '.php');
function __($langstring){
    if ($lang != 'en'){
        echo $langlist[$langstring];
    } else {
        echo $langstring;
    }
}
?>
```

But this doesn't work  (Notice: Undefined variable: lang and langlist).

What am I doing wrong?

**P.S.:** I know using `echo` instead of `return` inside a function ins't correct, but I don't want do be using `echo __();` every time I need to use this function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$lang` and `$langlist` are global variables, but they cannot be seen from within the function. Simply add the following as the first line of the function to gain access to them:

```
global $lang, $langlist;
```

Alternatively, you could access them as `$GLOBALS['lang']` and `$GLOBALS['langlist']` without using the `global` declaration.

Comment: It doesn't fully solves the problem. After the 12th time I use the `__()` function, it displays a "Notice: Undefined index: Array Key".

Comment: My bad! I forgot that I was using the `$langlist` twice.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
<?php $langlist = array { "Car" => "Carro", "Big Car" => "Carro grande"} ?>
```

should be

```
<?php $langlist = array("Car" => "Carro", "Big Car" => "Carro grande") ?>
```

Comment: Oops! My bad! This error is only in this question. The code already have the correct syntax. I guess this isn't the source of the problem... ;) (Corrected syntax in question.)